# How to display the content of an array using class attributes in TS?

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, class

This is the example code to add a single item out of a pre-written array to a table. There is only a single name element so I only need one "< td>${people[i]}< /td>" tag for the names to be displayed.

```
    let people: string [] = ["Jack", "Michael"]

    for (let i: number = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById ("buddies").innerHTML +=
    `<tr>
    <td>${people[i]}
    <tr>`;
    }
```

So how would I have to go about to get the same result if I want to use a class instead of simply writing the content into the array?

```
    class = Person{
    public FirstName : string
    public LastName : string
    constructor (Firstname: string, Lastname: string) {
       this.FirstName = Firstname;
       this.LastName = Lastname;}
    
    let people: Person [] = [
       new Person ("Peter", "Parker")]

    for (let i: number = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById ("table").innerHTML +=
    `<tr>
    <td>${people[i]}             //this is where the first name should be//
    <td>${people[i]}             //this is where the last name should be //
    <tr>`;
    }
```

I know that the current content of my < td> tags is nonsensical but I cannot wrap my head around how to assign the last and first name to the corresponding tag while still using my function, which is also inside of a renderlist. When opened in my browser I get [object Object] in my table row instead of "Peter Parker".

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case `people` is an array of instances of the class `Person`, objects of `Person`, and this class has the properties `FirstName` and `LastName`.

So now, when you iterate in your loop over `people`, to access its attributes you should do `people[i].FirstName` and `people[i].LastName`.

```
 for (let i: number = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById ("table").innerHTML +=
    `<tr>
    <td>${people[i].FirstName}             //this is where the first name should be//
    <td>${people[i].LastName}             //this is where the last name should be //
    <tr>`;
 }
```

So your code should look something like this:

```html
<table id="table"></table>

<script>
  // Made it with JS, but the class syntax is mostly the same in TS, since TS is a superscript of JS
  class Person{
      constructor (Firstname, Lastname) {
         this.FirstName = Firstname;
         this.LastName = Lastname;
         }
   }

  let people = [new Person ("Peter", "Parker"), new Person ("Jhonny", "Johnson")]

  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML +=
    `<tr>
    <td>${people[i].FirstName}
    <td>${people[i].LastName}
    <tr>`;
  }

</script>
```

Also, there are a few mistakes with your code, such as the class doesn't have an ending bracket, and also, to define a class it's just

```
class Person{
 ...
}
```

and not

```
class = Person{
  ...
}
```

More examples can be found in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html).